# D3 pinch to zoom doesn't work in v5, but works in v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming

Using two fingers to zoom on the touchpad on my mac works on D3v4:

https://jsfiddle.net/zshktfp9/2/

Click on the svg and zoom works like I would expect.

But the same code no longer works in v5:

https://jsfiddle.net/zshktfp9/4/

It no longer zooms within the svg, but the entire browser zooms.

I tried this on chrome and safari on mac and had a friend test it on windows chrome, the same break in functionality happens between v4 and v5.

```
    var zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", function() { grp.attr("transform", d3.event.transform) });
    svg.call(zoom);
```

As far as I could tell there is nothing I can find that I should be doing different in v5. Is there something I am missing, or is this a bug in D3.js?

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be a bug so I filed https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/204 - I'm not sure how to disable ctrl + click while enabling mac pinch-to-zoom so I couldn't create a pull request.

For now you can work around this by overriding the filter function:

```
d3.zoom().filter(() => !d3.event.button)...
```

Which restores v4 behavior.